# Proper syntax for BETWEEN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, between

```
$SQL="SELECT First_Name, Last_Name, Team, Pos, GP, G, A, (G+A) AS Points FROM stats ORDER BY Points DESC BETWEEN '$b1' AND '$b2'";
```

Giving me a `syntax error 'near 'BETWEEN '19' AND '17'' at line 1'`

(`19` and `17` are just variables a user inputs to replace `$b1` and `$b2` (between this and between this, etc)

Any suggestions?

Comment: BETWEEN won't work alone. You need something like `WHERE fieldname BETWEEN....`

Comment: Tried that, but unfortunately it just returns that Points is not a proper column (Which it isnt, its just a variable made up from integers from two other columns.)

Comment: ...and the `ORDER BY` should be after the `WHERE`

Comment: 'WHERE Points BETWEEN '$b1' AND '$b2' ORDER BY Points DESC' returns with Unknown column 'Points' in 'where clause'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a field alias in that `WHERE` clause. What you **can** do is use your assignment again in the `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT 
    First_Name, 
    Last_Name, 
    Team, 
    Pos, GP, G, A, 
    (G+A) AS Points 
FROM stats 
WHERE 
    (G+A) BETWEEN '$b1' AND '$b2'
ORDER BY Points DESC
```

> Standard SQL doesn't allow you to refer to a column alias in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE code is executed, the column value may not yet be determined.

MySQL docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html

Answer (score 1):

The [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) describes the syntax of `BETWEEN`:

```
expr BETWEEN min AND max

If expr is greater than or equal to min and expr is less than or equal to max, 
BETWEEN returns 1, otherwise it returns 0
```

There are two problems in your case:

1. `BETWEEN` will always return 0, since 19 > 17.
2. It's hard to say without more context, but I think in your case, you want to use `BETWEEN` as part of a `WHERE` clause. For example, `WHERE Points BETWEEN 17 AND 19`